# Why can't a permanent magnet's magnetic field be converted into other types of energy?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, unit-conversion

Can a solid magnet excite any type of atom's electrons to release photons?
Why can't magnets be arranged to be its own generator? is there an equation for reason solid magnets can't self perpetuate?

[image]

[image]

[Sources](https://www.google.com/search?q=magnet%20generator&client=ubuntu&hs=pk0&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOqPWwx97PAhUGLSYKHZBvCKUQ_AUICigD&biw=1280&bih=675#q=magnet%20generator&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg%3ACd-nLoygdlbMIjiHOmioR_1Xja80oZUT91skQBahcnAoYsOft0ONVKxjdQKZPQSZGr6Dcq0QpjWgZDYAjk8bqV9DdiioSCYc6aKhH9eNrEQ8FHmY4nMMIKhIJzShlRP3WyRARoz4SSNZ0StIqEgkFqFycChiw5xFHA8uZTzTzGSoSCe3Q41UrGN1AEQetJwVKJ2wPKhIJpk9BJkavoNwRgMY87J54iNkqEgmrRCmNaBkNgBEIvtzNqYX-bioSCSOTxupX0N2KEczCfw3s5DKU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why can't a permanent magnet's magnetic field be converted other types of energy?

A permanent magnet's magnetic field can be changed to other forms of energy. If you heat the magnet enough it will lose its magnetic field and the energy stored in the magnetic field will turn into some more heat.

> Can a solid magnet excite any type of atom's electrons to release photons?

A magnet can excite electrons, but it has to be in motion relative to the atoms. After all that is how an electricity generator works.

> Why can't magnets be arranged to be its own generator?

Magnets are used to generate electricity.

> is there an equation for this?

The complete set of equations about magnets and electricity are called Maxwell's equations.

Comment: In a typical generator the energy for the developed current comes from the mechanical driving force and *not* form the magnetic field (which is part of the mechanism but is not left any weaker for having been used in that way).

Answer (score 2):

Permanent magnet lose magnetism over a period of time. They are not reliable for long term power generation. That's why electromagnets come into picture. You need the initial boost from an external power source and once the generator is in motion, it can keep the magnet excited from the electricity produced. Not much of power is wasted on electromagnets anyway.

Comment: neodymium magnets will likely lose less than1% of their flux density over 100 years